# What happen when we remove the @Repository in DAO layer in spring?

Tags: spring-mvc

What happens when we remove the `@Repository` annotation in DAO layer in spring?

```
@Repository 
public class EmployeeService {

    // ....

    @Transactional
    public int createEmployee(Employee emp) {
        //create Employee
        employeeDao.createEmployee(emp);

        User user = new User();
        // some fileds of employee are used to create a User
        user.setEmployeeId(emp.getEmployeeId());
        // ....

        userDao.createUser(user);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You will get: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'employeeService'`

[@Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) is to create a bean and it indicates that the annotated class is a *Repository*.

- Either you can keep `@Repository` or you can add a bean definition in `applicationContext.xml`
- On removing `@Repository` and no bean specified in `applicationContext.xml`

  Result: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'employeeService'`

Answer (score 1):

You will get the following exception if you are not using any annotation or not created respective in the xml configuration.
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'employeeService'